# Histogram function plots different colours from those requested

Tags: matlab

I"m trying to color-code each of 4 histograms using a predefined color scheme. Here's a minimal working example:

```
colours = [0 32 96;
    192 0 0;
    71 207 255;
    255 143 143;
    ] / 255;

for i=1:4
    x = randn(1,100);
    subplot(1,4, i)
    values = histogram(x,   'FaceColor', colours (i, :));
end
```

However, in the image I'm getting, the colors are actually (slightly) different, for instance for the first histogram I get (102,121,160) instead of (0,32,96):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `histogram` `FaceAlpha` is `0.6` [(ref.)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram-properties.html). Setting it to `1` should do the trick.

```
histogram(x,'FaceColor',[0 1 0],'FaceAlpha',1);
```

Very cumbersome and unexpected.